# Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow error after adding code to load coordinates from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, coordinates

I am creating an app that has imageButton buildings that the user can purchase. When they are purchased they are put onto the users layout and are then drag and drop. When the user moves the building the coordinates are automatically saved when it is dropped. My issue is that after adding in the functions to load the coordinates back up, I get the error that I posted in my logcat. I have seen this question many times and have tried all that I have seen with no luck. Please help guys. Thanks.

Here are my column names:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ROCK = "amount_of_rock";
public static final String KEY_METEORROCK = "amount_of_meteor_rock";
public static final String KEY_WATER = "amount_of_water";
public static final String KEY_SHOVEL = "shovel_level";
public static final String KEY_SHOVELEXP = "shovel_experience";
public static final String KEY_BUCKET = "bucket_level";
public static final String KEY_BUCKETEXP = "bucket_experience";
public static final String KEY_PICKAXE = "pickaxe_level";
public static final String KEY_PICKAXEEXP = "pickaxe_experience";
public static final String KEY_POPULATION = "population";
public static final String KEY_MAINHUTLEVEL = "main_hut_level";
public static final String KEY_MAINHUTHEALTH = "main_hut_health";
public static final String KEY_MAINHUTX = "main_hut_x_coord";
public static final String KEY_MAINHUTY = "main_hut_y_ coord";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "2023db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "maintable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Here is my code for getting the saved coordinates of the mainHut (the line that the error occurs on has a comment next to it in the getMainHutY function):

```
public float getMainHutX() 
{
    float mainHutX = 0;
    int iMainHutX = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
            KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
            KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP, KEY_MAINHUTLEVEL, KEY_MAINHUTHEALTH, 
            KEY_MAINHUTX, KEY_MAINHUTY};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            iMainHutX = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MAINHUTX);
            mainHutX = c.getFloat(iMainHutX);
        }//end if
        c.close();
        return mainHutX;
    }//end if
    return 0;
}//end getMainHutX function

public float getMainHutY() 
{
    float mainHutY = 0;
    int iMainHutY = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
            KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
            KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP, KEY_MAINHUTLEVEL, KEY_MAINHUTHEALTH, 
            KEY_MAINHUTX, KEY_MAINHUTY};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            iMainHutY = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MAINHUTY);
            mainHutY = c.getFloat(iMainHutY); //error occurs here
        }//end if
        c.close();
        return mainHutY;
    }//end if
    return 0;
}//end getMainHutY function
```

Here is my logcat:

```
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/CursorWindow(561): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 15 columns.
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Process: com.twentytwentythree.sab, PID: 561
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twentytwentythree.sab/com.project.llb.runGraphics}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:668)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetDouble(Native Method)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getDouble(CursorWindow.java:597)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getFloat(CursorWindow.java:648)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getFloat(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:81)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.twentytwentythree.sab.Database.getMainHutY(Database.java:228)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.twentytwentythree.sab.runGraphics.onCreate(runGraphics.java:142)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
10-02 22:32:18.036: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could show what the column name constants are (especially for KEY_MAINHUTY.)

In any case, after looking this over, the only thing I can conclude is that the table you are querying does not have a column with the name specified by KEY_MAINHUTY.

Can you verify that your table does indeed have a column with the name specified by KEY_MAINHUTY?

The call to c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MAINHUTY); is returning -1, yet that column name is clearly specified in your columns array.

Comment: sorry about that. I added the column name declarations.

Comment: This made me feel really stupid...but as soon as I posted the declarations I realized what the issue was...I had a space in the string after the declaration of the coordinate I was having issues with. Thank you, I would not have seen it without this.